# Setup wifi configurations for Broadcom43142

Tags: linux, networking, broadcom, lfs

I'm working on a custom version of Linux distro (more specifically, the LFS project) which means I don't have a package manager and I install packages manually.

I try to setup the BCM43142 pci card (Broadcom's wifi card). I managed to find the correct driver and to install it
(the driver is https://www.broadcom.com/support/download-search/?pf=Wireless+LAN+Infrastructure I followed the instructions written there)

nevertheless, the output of 'iwconfig' is:

```
wlp2s0    no wireless extensions.
sit0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Can anyone point out what else should I do to make my distro recognize the card's wireless capabilities ?

I'm running 4.9.9 kernel

## insmod wl.ko

```
[   35.865452] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   35.865485] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   35.865509] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   35.907750] wl 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from eth0
[   36.000340] wlp2s0: Broadcom BCM4365 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)

[   36.000507] insmod (254) used greatest stack depth: 11560 bytes left
```

## lspci -n

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0611]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-f2-ff-ff-d8-80-56
    Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

## lshw -c Network

```
-b0403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 80:56:f2:d8:62:93
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:16 memory:b0500000-b0507fff
```

I am aware that it writes 'BCM4365' after 'insmod'. On my Ubuntu it writes the same and the WIFI works

Answer (score 0):

Disable the secure boot.

You can manually compile the driver or automatically through `dkms` (see [broadcom-wl on github](https://github.com/antoineco/broadcom-wl))

Create a blacklist file for ssb , bcma , b43 and brcmsmac modules then run:

```
git clone https://github.com/antoineco/broadcom-wl.git
make 
make install
depmod -A
modprobe wl
```

Comment: hi, sorry for the time it took me to answer, when disabling fastboot I realized that my OS wasn't booting in EFI mode but rather than in legacy mode.

it took me quite a while to configure it properly so it would boot in EFI.
anyhow, I did all you wrote here and the module does load at startup but I still get the same 'dmesg' output and and still no wireless extension when typing 'iwconfiig'

Answer (score 0):

This guy got his BCM43142 working as noted in this comment of a solution to BCM4320.

[Broadcom Wireless PCI Card BMC4360 14e4:43a0 cannot get drivers working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440143/broadcom-wireless-pci-card-bmc4360-14e443a0-cannot-get-drivers-working?rq=1#comment941675_441256)